# Database design - custom and predefined attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, lumen, entity-attribute-value

I am creating an APP, similar to OLX. From server end I'm using Laravel's Lumen. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to store assigned attributes to ads. Of course I know there are maaaany ways, but I need to find the best way to make it very efficient.

I've got two ideas, and both of them seems to be bad ;)

**1.** Creating separete row for each attribute assigned to an ad like:

```
| id | ad_id | attribute_id | value |
| 1  |  1    |      12      |  new  |
| 2  |  1    |      17      | wooden|
| 3  |  1    |     123      |  114  |
```

but it seems to lead to problems in the future when there will be millions assigned attributes

**2.** on the other hand creating serialized values is not easily searchable, while trying to filter ads by attributes.

```
| id | ad_id | attribute_value |
| 1  |  1    |a:3:{i:0;a:1:{i:12;s:3:"new";}i:1;a:1:{i:17;s:6:"wooden";}i:2;a:1:{i:123;s:3:"114";}}|
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've decided not to use any multivalued attributes, but I'll try to make clear the rest of my problems:

After following some advises I divided all the attributes into 3 groups:

**1.** Not searchable, serialized, stored directly in ads table - seems to be the best choice for values that I just need to display.

**2.** with predefined selection choices using 3 tables:

**Attributes:**

```
id   | name   | slug   | category     | type    | required    | purpose
  1  | Color  | color  | 2            | select  | true        | both
```

**Attribute values:**

```
id  | attribute_id  | value | slug
1   | 23            | Blue  | blue
2   | 23            | Red   | red
3   | 23            | Green | green
```

**Attribute relations:**

```
id  | attribute_val_id  | ad_id
1   | 24                | 54
```

**3.** And third, attribute values entered by user:

**Attributes:**

```
id   | name   | slug   | category     | type    | required  | purpose
  2  | Size   | size   | 234          | input   | true      | both
```

**Custom attributes:**

```
id  | attribute_id  | value | ad_id
1   | 24            | 2052  | 54
```

Is it the best approach?

Comment: If you are using Relational Database Management System, then, just normalize your data. Avoid non 1NF.

Comment: multi valued attributes are pretty hard to normalize @daniherrera

Comment: An EAV table would fit here

Comment: I see no multivalued attributes in the question, only dynamic single-valued attributes. Multivalued attributes refer to attributes which can have multiple values, for example a person can have multiple given names. MVAs aren't hard to normalize. EAV tables on the other hand aren't relations since the relational model doesn't include dependent types, and so normalization doesn't apply.